# Improper integral $ \int\limits_0^1\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\frac{1}{t})}{t^4}+(\cos(t)-t\sin(t))^2+4t^2}~~dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Show that the improper integral

$$
\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\frac{1}{t})}{t^4}+(\cos(t)-t\sin(t))^2+4t^2}~~dt
$$
doesn't exist.

---

My first attempt was looking for a lower bound of the integrand:

$\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\frac{1}{t})}{t^4}+(\cos(t)-t\sin(t))^2+4t^2}\geq \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2}$ which leads to the integral

$$\int\limits_a^1 \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2}=\sin(\frac{1}{t})\Big|_a^1.$$
Letting $a\to 0 $, we see that due to periodicity of the $\sin$-function that the limit doesn't exist.

However, this only delivers an integral that doesn't diverge to $\infty$ so I can't use this fact to show that the original integral doesn't exist.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The integral is at least as large as

$$\int_0^1\frac{|\cos (1/t)|}{t^2}\,dt.$$

Now let $t=1/s$ to see the last integral is

$$\int_1^\infty |\cos s |\, ds = \infty.$$

Comment: Intuitively the equation $\int_1^\infty |\cos s |\, ds = \infty$ is clear. If I want to argue  rigorously I have to split the integral into countable many pieces, like $\int_{1}^{n}|cos(s)| \, ds=\int_{1}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|cos(s)| \, ds+\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\int_{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}^{(k+1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}|cos(s)| \, ds$. Then, by letting $n\to\infty$ I get $\int_1^\infty |\cos s |\, ds = \infty$, right?

Comment: @Philipp  Yes, when you first encounter such integrals, you should be rigorous. After a while, you'll just nod your head and move on.

Answer (score 0):

We want to investigate
$$\int\limits_0^1 f(t) \, dt $$
where
$$ f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\frac{1}{t})}{t^4}+(\cos(t)-t\sin(t))^2+4t^2}$$

Following your answer,but noting that $\cos \frac1t $ may be negative,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\frac{1}{t})}{t^4}+(\cos(t)-t\sin(t))^2+4t^2}\geqslant \left| \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2} \right| $$

We therefore write (setting $u=\frac1t$):

$$\int\limits_0^1 f(t) \, dt  \geqslant \int\limits_0^1 \left| \frac{\cos(\frac{1}{t})}{t^2} \right|  \, dt  = \int\limits_1^\infty  \left| u^2 \cos u  \right|  \frac{1}{u^2} \, du = \int\limits_1^\infty  \left|  \cos u  \right|   \, du  $$

which clearly diverges.